# "Order" of values in Bundle

Tags: java, android

If I put several items in Bundle, can I rely that I'll get them out in the same order when I for-each the keys of the bundle?

For example:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1", "A");
bundle.putString("key2", "B");
bundle.putString("key3", "C");
```

Can I rely that after the following code

```
String concat = "";
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
   concat += bundle.get(key).toString();
}
```

the value of `concat` will be `"ABC"`?

Comment: Up to I know it's gonna be performed as synchronous task so it's not gonna be executed in  order.

Comment: You've missed the most important piece of information.  Why?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Iterator returned by the bundle keySet() function belongs to the underlying Java class "Set". This iterator is unordered. for more details see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html#iterator()

You can order your keySet by using a sorted map:

SortedMap orderedMap = new TreeMap(originalMap);

Answer (score 3):

What about looking inside `Bundle` source code? It is build up with `HashMap` inside, which doesn't guarantee the original keys order. So answer will be **no**.

Comment: Android 5.0 at least uses an `ArrayMap`, but that too does not guarantee the order of the keys AFAICT.